# 2003 Honda Accord - driver side low beam light bulb replacement

Tags: honda, headlight, accord

I've been researching this because I figured that I can do this myself. I was able to change the passenger side one once before.

On the driver side, the battery is in the way so it is impossible to reach inside the hood to change it.

Two techniques are on the web:
(1) Take out the battery and then reach into the hood
(2) Remove a plastic protective cover from inside the driver-side wheel well to access the bulb.

I bought this car used and don't have the code for the radio (if I take out the battery, I will be required to enter a code once I reconnect the battery)

Any advice on how I should proceed?

Comment: I actually removed the battery and the driver side low beams were easy to access. I didn't buy a settings saver because I found the radio security code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask at your local auto parts store you should be able to purchase a "settinigs saver". one type is basically a 9 volt battery and an adapter that plugs into the power outlet/cigarette lighter. The 9V battery maintains the settings until the battery is reconnected. Another type has two power plugs, one plugs into the power outlet and the other end plugs into another vehicle or a portable jumpstarter.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably lift out the battery without actually removing the terminals (be careful not to short them, though!), or you could attach a supplemental battery with jumper cables while removing the main battery. However, since you'll eventually do something stupid like leaving your headlights on and run down the battery, you should probably figure out how to bypass or reset the radio code. I hear there are websites with that information; perhaps someone more familiar with the topic can fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to remove the battery you may remove the driver side wheel well housing and access it from there